# Why is it necessary to install Browserify twice to bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I created a new project

I `npm install -g browserify`

I tested using the cmdline, `browserify app.js > bundle.js`. Cool.

I want to minify so I `npm install uglifyify --save-dev`

I tested using the cmdline, `browserify -g uglifyify app.js > bundle.js`. Great.

Now I want to do this with code, but I get `Error: Cannot find module 'browserify'`

This is my code, basically to replace the cmdline

```
var browserify = require('browserify')
var fs = require('fs')

var bundler = browserify('./app.js')

bundler.transform({
    global: true
}, 'uglifyify')

bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./bundle.js'))
```

It seems I would need to again install browserify locally to this project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing an npm module like `browserify` allows you to use `browserify` as a command on the command line. To use the module within your project's code, you must install the module as a dependency. In other words, yes, is must be installed locally within the project's `./node_modules` folder and referenced in the `package.json` file.

From the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders):

> - Local install (default): puts stuff in `./node_modules` of the current package root.
> - Global install (with `-g`): puts stuff in `/usr/local` or wherever node is installed.
> - Install it locally if you're going to `require()` it.
> - Install it globally if you're going to run it on the command line.
> - If you need both, then install it in both places, or use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Answer (score 5):

As said in the other answer, one way to solve this is that you can install browserify locally instead of globally, like: `npm install --save browserify uglifyfy`. Then you can add a `script` in `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "browserify app.js > bundle.js",
   ...
},
...
```

Now, `npm run-script build` will know how to find local browserify, which is going to be in your `node_modules/` directory. And your `require('browserify')` will work, since browserify is now local.

---

Another way you could solve this is `NODE_PATH` env variable. Set this variable in your `bashrc` or equivalent like this:

```
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules
```

Adjust the path to wherever your global node_modules are. Then you can `require()` whatever you installed with -g flag in your code.

However this is suboptimal, as it can lead to errors and misunderstandings. But if it's for some quick-and-dirty scripts, it can help.