# ReferenceError: require is not defined - browserify - generator-angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm trying to use [node-geocoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder), which uses `require` so I install [browserify](http://browserify.org/#install) by `sudo npm install -g browserify`, and I think I'm stuck on bundling all by `browserify <some_file>.js -o src/assets/bundle.js`. I'm not sure which file I should choose, so I chose that were I want to use `node-geocoder` (`create.controller.js`) Finally I added `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` to my `index.html`
But I still getting ReferenceError

```
angular.js:13550 ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at new CreateController
```

`create.controller.js`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('untitled')
    .controller('CreateController', CreateController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function CreateController($http, $log) {

    var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

    var options = {
      provider: 'google',
      httpAdapter: 'https', // Default
      apiKey: 'myApiKey',
      formatter: 'string'
    };

    var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);


    geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris')
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

I use [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)
I'm very new at JS and all these frameworks, so I hope that I posted all needed information.

Comment: so the entry point for browserify should be the first file that begins requiring dependencies. im not sure how the rest of your project is set up but i dont think you will only be able to use browserify on one controller and include it via a script tag and expect it to work with the rest of your app which is not using browserify. Also looking at the node-geocoder module it doesn't say anything about it working on the client side, so even if you do get it working that module may depend on things only available in Node.

Comment: That's very importart information, that some plugins won't work on client-side. I think I just gonna look for other plugin or just use plain google geocoder. Right now I think I lack of experience to do this.

Comment: @JakubPomykała install browserify module local instead of global (-g) --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992104/why-is-it-necessary-to-install-browserify-twice-to-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Require() isnt a valid function in client sided JavaScript.
Try using RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html)

For help with RequireJS' API, http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Comment: `require()` will work client side when using browserify like he is doing